# How to receive and save JSON string in web api

Tags: c#, json, rest

What's a simple way to implement POST to save JSON data to a local text file ? I keep getting null value when I use [FromBody] and without it it doesn't find the POST resource. 
Basically i would like to save the raw data to a regular text file located in the App_Data folder for example. 
Thanks.

Here is my controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string jsonstring)
      {        

          string json1 = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/post.txt");
          string outp = jsonstring.ToString();
          File.WriteAllText(json1, outp);

          return new HttpResponseMessage()
         {
             StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created
         };

      }
```

And sample json data that I'm trying to POST

```
{"system":{"programs":null,"info":null,"types":{"type1":"data1","type2":"data2",‌​"type3":"data3","type4":"data4","type5":"data5"},"name":"name1","name2":"name2","‌​sys":{"sys1":"info","sysv":"123"}},"files":{"file1":null,"file2":null,"file3":nul‌​l,"file4":"AA","file5":"11111","file6":null,"file7":"11131","fil38":null,"files5"‌​:null}}
```

This is the error I get at this line: string outp = jsonstring.ToString();

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=test
  StackTrace:
       at test.Controllers.testController.Post(String jsonstring) in c:\Users\test\test\Controllers\testController.cs:line 36
       at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ExecuteAsync>b__4()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException:
```

the raw code from fiddler, but I get the same error event I just put Hello word only in the body.. so I don't think it's json related error

```
POST http://localhost:3281/api/test HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:3281
Content-Length: 357

{"system":{"programs":null,"info":null,"types":{"type1":"data1","type2":"data2",‌​"type3":"data3","type4":"data4","type5":"data5"},"name":"name1","name2":"name2","‌​sys":{"sys1":"info","sysv":"123"}},"files":{"file1":null,"file2":null,"file3":nul‌​l,"file4":"AA","file5":"11111","file6":null,"file7":"11131","fil38":null,"files5"‌​:null}}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code so we can try to see what's wrong.

Comment: Could you edit your question with the code in your controller? It sounds like the controller method is what we're trying to troubleshoot. Please include your use of [FromBody].

Comment: There are many things that could go wrong when trying to POST data to a route. I don't think we can tell what's going on without at least some server-side code. It would also be helpful to know how you're POSTing the data so we can see if something is wrong with the way you're submitting the request. Generally though you should be able to google for a WebAPI tutorial that will walk you through this. If there are confusing parts of the tutorial though, we could help fill in the gaps.

Comment: ok I updated the question with my controller code..

Comment: Cool, thanks. Could you also post the code you use the make the POST request? I don't see anything wrong with this method. Does it find your route (in other words, do you get a 404)?

Comment: Fails at this line: string outp = jsonstring.ToString();
I updated the initial post with error

Comment: Okay, but how are you calling the Post method? Can you show the code that calls it? Maybe it's not being called correctly and that's actually where the problem is.

Comment: Maybe I need to use httpcontext to grab the data from body ? I just need to take the data from the POST body and save to a text file as it is

Comment: No, I mean how are you actually submitting the data to the server? Whatever code does that is what we need to see. For example, using jQuery, it might look something like: `$.post('/foo-route', data)`

Comment: It's a regular http client, no jquery. It's sending the data as Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8. I'm using fiddler and postman right now to get it working

Comment: If I put "hello" in the body it works. I came across this: "When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header to select a formatter. In this example, the content type is "application/json" and the request body is a raw JSON string (not a JSON object)."
Does this mean I need to deserialize the json in order to save it as regular text ?

Comment: See the answer I posted. I think you just need to format your JSON object differently.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're sending your data as a JSON object and not as a string, the Post method can't bind your object (because the method expects a string, not an object).

Also, I believe the JSON you posted isn't valid JSON. Try sending something simpler first just while you get the route working. Be sure the JSON you're sending is valid (I use jsonlint.com to test).

Here's an example of what you could post:

```
{
    "jsonstring": "foo"
}
```

I haven't tested this, but when you POST this, `jsonstring` should bind correctly to the parameter you have in the Post method, and the value of that string should be "foo". Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. The sample json I posted is valid it's just a very complex json data and I just need something quick and dirty rather than writing all the models and database to implement it the "normal" way..

Comment: When you use my example, do you get a different error?

Comment: no, same exact.. I probably need to treat the data as regular text somehow before I attempt to save it..

Comment: I think I need a way just to capture the raw data the save it to text file.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your request needs to use **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

```
POST http://localhost:3281/api/test HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:3281
Content-Length: 357
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try changing content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and didn't work. But in my case I cannot change client to send content type other then application/json.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution

```
    [HttpPost]

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var jsonString = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        string json1 = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/Post.txt");

        File.WriteAllText(json1, jsonString);

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
```